# Infinite updating of the RecyclerView list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java2, android-mvvm

With the help of dagger and rxJava I update the list in a RecyclerView. Everything works well, the list is displayed. But the problem is that in the logs I see how this list is updated every second. What could be the problem? In a similar project but in Java everything works correctly, the list is updated once at startup.
My Network Module:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class NetworkModule {

    companion object {
        const val KEY = "key"
        const val BASE_URL = "base_url"
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttp(): OkHttpClient {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpClient.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
                val original = chain.request()
                val originalHttpUrl = original.url
                val url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                    //.addQueryParameter("apikey", KEY)
                    .build()
                val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .url(url)
                    .header("apikey", KEY)
                val request = requestBuilder.build()
                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
        })
        // logging interceptor
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)
        return httpClient.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(provideOkHttp())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContactsService(retrofit: Retrofit) : ContactsService{

        return retrofit.create(ContactsService::class.java)
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class ContactsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val contactsRepository: ContactsRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    var mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<ContactsModel>>()
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun getContactMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<List<ContactsModel>> {
        loadData()
        return mutableLiveData
    }

    fun loadData() {

       disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<ContactsModel>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<ContactsModel>) {
                getContactMutableLiveData().value = t
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }
            })
        )
    }
}
```

And my Activity:

```
contactsViewModel.getContactMutableLiveData().observe(this@ContactListActivity, Observer {

            mAdapter = ContactsAdapter(this@ContactListActivity, it as ArrayList<ContactsModel>)
            recycler_contacts.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false)
            recycler_contacts.adapter = mAdapter
            recycler_contacts.setHasFixedSize(true)

            mAdapter.sortByName()

        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a logical error. You need to rewrite the loadData function as shown below

```
class ContactsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val contactsRepository: ContactsRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    var mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<ContactsModel>>()
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun getContactMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<List<ContactsModel>> {

        disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<ContactsModel>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<ContactsModel>) {
                    mutableLiveData.value = t
                }
                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }
            }))
        return mutableLiveData
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you only want to update your data list only once... I would recommend you look into a single live event that would trigger the reloading of your recycler view 
As such

```
//in repo
private SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> listHasBeenUpdate=new SingleLiveEvent<>();
//setItsGetterInTheRepo
public SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> getListHasBeenUpdated(){
return listHasBeenUpdated();
}
//uponSucessfuly fetching your list from retrofit
listHasBeenUpdated=true;
//pass list to viewmodel
```

then in the ViewModel, I would set the list to be an Observable Data which would be updated once it's fetched from retrofit (Consider [using room db](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942) to store this)

```
//use a setter to set the list from Repo
ObservableField<List<Contacts>> list=new ObservableField<>();

public SingleLiveEvent<List<Contacts>> fetchContacts(){
   return myRepo.getListHasBeenUpdated();
}
```

In your activity class now observe the single live event like so

```
viewModel.fetchContacts().observe(this,contacts->{
  if(contacts){
    //update Recycler
  }
});
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Where did Private private SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> listHasBeenUpdate=new SingleLiveEvent<>(); ? What is SingleListEvent<Boolean>?

Comment: The private single live event checks for updating of the list it is triggered only once you, therefore, don't need to set it back to false so once it has been observed it will be observed once some changes have been made to the boolean event again...

Comment: also, I apologize my response is in Java and not Kotlin but the solution can be applied to both Java and Kotlin